# moving rows in js. can anyone tell how to move selected rows back to main table

Tags: lightning-web-components, general

```javascript
moveDown() {
    var selectedRecords =  
    this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();  
    console.log('selectedRecords',selectedRecords)
    this.selectedRows = selectedRecords;
    var data1=[];
    for(let i = 0 ; i< this.data.length; i++){
        var rec =  this.data[i];
        var isTrue = true;
        for(let i=0 ; i<this.selectedRows.length;i++){
            var srec = this.selectedRows[i];
            if(srec.Id==rec.Id ){
                isTrue = false;
            }
        }
        if(isTrue){
            data1.push(rec) ;
        }
    }
    this.data = [...data1];
}

moveUp(){
    var data2=[];
    for(let i = 0 ; i< this.data1.length; i++){
        var rec =  this.data1[i];
        var isTrue = true;
        for(let i=0 ; i<this.selectedRows.length;i++){
             var srec = this.selectedRows[i];
               if(srec.Id==rec.Id ){
                   isTrue = false;
               }
        }
        if(isTrue){
            data.push(rec) ;
        }
    }
    this.selectedRows = [...data];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the elements one at a time. That looks something like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

function swap(data, index1, index2) {
  const temp = data[index1];
  data[index1] = data[index2];
  data[index2] = temp;
}

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  columns = [{ fieldName: "name", label: "Name" }];
  data = [
    { id: "1", name: "Alice" },
    { id: "2", name: "Bob" },
    { id: "3", name: "Charles" },
    { id: "4", name: "Diana" },
    { id: "5", name: "Edward" },
    { id: "6", name: "Felicia" },
  ];
  moveUp() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
      "lightning-datatable"
    ).selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows) {
      for (const rowId of selectedRows) {
        const index = this.data.findIndex((row) => row.id === rowId);
        if (index > 0) {
          swap(this.data, index, index - 1);
        }
      }
      this.data = [...this.data];
    }
  }
  moveDown() {
    // Since we're copying upwards, we need to go backwards
    const selectedRows = [
      ...this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").selectedRows,
    ];
    selectedRows.reverse();
    if (selectedRows) {
      for (const rowId of selectedRows) {
        const index = this.data.findIndex((row) => row.id === rowId);
        if (index < this.data.length - 1) {
          swap(this.data, index, index + 1);
        }
      }
    }
    this.data = [...this.data];
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/h8pnBe5XoI1h7z5loQpf/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: thanks for your reference. but I am trying to swap rows between two tables. just in UI. no server-side changes

Comment: @Riyaz I misunderstood your original question, the edit helped. See new answer.

Comment: is It possible for both Dynamic and static data? like fetching data from salesforce org and swapping rows above.

Comment: @Riyaz Sure. My code example is written to be self-contained, but you can source the data from anywhere you'd like.

Comment: I try the below code. buttons are not working for dynamic data                ,@track data1;
@track Keyfield = 'id';
@wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.data1 = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify( this.data1));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

Comment: @Riyaz Data you get from the wire is read-only. This is to protect cache coherency. Do this instead: `this.data1 = [...data]` to copy the array and unlock it for modification.

Comment: this.data1 = [...data] if I do this instead. it will throw an error Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not iterable

Comment: @Riyaz You have a mistake in your code. `this.data` is not `data`.

Comment: Ill Share my modified code onec @sfdxfox

Answer (score 0):

You can move them between tables just by removing the elements from the old list and adding them to the new list. That would look something like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  columns = [{ fieldName: "name", label: "Name" }];
  data1 = [
    { id: "1", name: "Alice" },
    { id: "2", name: "Bob" },
    { id: "3", name: "Charles" },
    { id: "4", name: "Diana" },
    { id: "5", name: "Edward" },
    { id: "6", name: "Felicia" },
  ];
  data2 = [];
  moveUp() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
      ".table2"
    ).selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data1 = [...this.data1, ...this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
      this.data2 = this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
      this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
      this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
    }
  }
  moveDown() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
      ".table1"
    ).selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data2 = [...this.data2, ...this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
      this.data1 = this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
      this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
      this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/pvxTQgXJY0EJPf8LdQaW/src/app.js?p=stories).

---

Edit: Fixes to your latest code version:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import getAccountList from "@salesforce/apex/accountCreationController.getAccountList";
export default class DemoSwap extends LightningElement {
  columns = [
    { label: "Account Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
    { label: "Industry", fieldName: "Industry", type: "text" },
    { label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "Phone" },
  ];
  // To show values on the tables
  data1 = [];
  data2 = [];
  @wire(getAccountList)
  wiredAccounts({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        // [...data] to make a shallow copy
      this.data1 = [...data];
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  }
  moveUp() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(".table2").selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data1 = [
        ...this.data1,
        ...this.data2.filter((row) => selectedRows.indexOf(row.id) > -1),
      ];
      this.data2 = this.data2.filter(
        (row) => selectedRows.indexOf(row.id) === -1
      );
      this.data1.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      this.data2.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }
  }
  moveDown() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(".table1").selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data2 = [
        ...this.data2,
        ...this.data1.filter((row) => selectedRows.indexOf(row.id) > -1),
      ];
      this.data1 = this.data1.filter(
        (row) => selectedRows.indexOf(row.id) === -1
      );
      this.data1.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      this.data2.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: @Riyaz See my edits for the latest version on this answer.

Comment: thank you. I am able to display data. but rows are not moving

Comment: if check console.logs. selected data are displayed. can we use find and slice or Map? because selected rows are not moving up and down.

Comment: @Riyaz My apologies for missing this comment, I just saw your new question. You have some typos in your code. Make sure you're starting from this exact code before adding the wire method in. It does work as written here.

Answer (score 0):

```
`import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/accountCreationController.getAccountList';
export default class DemoSwap extends LightningElement {
  columns = [
    {label:'Account Name',fieldName:'Name',type:'text'},
    {label:'Industry',fieldName:'Industry',type:'text'},       
    {label:'Phone', fieldName:'Phone', type:'Phone'}
 ];

@track data;
data1=[];
@wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({data,error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.data = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
    data1=[...this.data];
  data2 = [];
  moveUp() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
      ".table2"
    ).selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data1 = [...this.data1, ...this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
      this.data2 = this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
      this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
      this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
    }
 
  }
  moveDown() {
    const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
      ".table1"
    ).selectedRows;
    if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
      this.data2 = [...this.data2, ...this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
      this.data1 = this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
      this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
      this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you edit your original question to update it; this sort of "answer" will be deleted sooner or later. I'll review this and let you know.

Comment: ok. thank you for your help