# Moving rows between two table for single object for Dynamic Data in LWC component in UI. I got till getting data into DATA TABLE can you please help

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

```
    <!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
    <template>
        <lightning-Card title="Account List" icon-name="standard:account">
            <h1>table 1</h1>    
        <!-- <template if:true={data1}> -->
            <lightning-button label="Move Down" onclick={moveDown}>
            </lightning-button>
        <lightning-datatable class="table1" data={data1} columns={columns} key-field="id">
        </lightning-datatable>
        <h1>Table 2</h1>
        <lightning-datatable class="table2" data={data2} columns={columns} key-field="id">
        </lightning-datatable>
        <lightning-button label="Move Up" onclick={moveUp}>
        </lightning-button>
    <!-- </template> -->
        <!-- <template if:true={error}>
            {error}
        </template> -->
    </lightning-Card>
    </template>
```

---

```
    import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
    import getAccountList from "@salesforce/apex/accountCreationController.getAccountList";
    export default class DemoSwap extends LightningElement {
      columns = [
        { label: "Account Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
        { label: "Industry", fieldName: "Industry", type: "text" },
        { label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "Phone" },
      ];
      // To show values on the tables
      data2 = [];
      data1=[];
      @wire(getAccountList)
      wiredAccounts({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            // [...data] to make a shallow copy
          this.data1 = [...data]; 
          alert(JSON.stringify(this.data1));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data1));
                } else if (error) {
          this.error = error;
        }
      }
      moveUp() {
        var selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
          "lightning-datatable"
        ).getselectedRows;
        if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
          alert(this.selectedRows)
          this.data1 = [...this.data1, ...this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
          this.data2 = this.data2.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
          this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
          this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
        }
      }
      moveDown() {
        var selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(
          "lightning-datatable"
        ).getselectedRows;
        if (selectedRows && selectedRows.length) {
          this.data2 = [...this.data2, ...this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)>-1)];
          this.data1 = this.data1.filter((row)=>selectedRows.indexOf(row.id)===-1);
          this.data1.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
          this.data2.sort((a,b) => (a.id-b.id));
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
public class accountCreationController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
 public static List<Account> getAccountList(){
            return [Select Id, Name, Industry, AnnualRevenue, Phone From Account Where Industry !=null order by createdDate desc];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
).getselectedRows;
```

Should be:

```
).selectedRows;
```

And, since you have two tables, you need to make sure you get the correct table.

Please compare your code to [my code from your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/381572/2984).

Comment: if I replace getselectedRows; as selectedRows . the rows are not moving. if selected querySelector as class .table1 or .table2 it also not working

Comment: @Riyaz Again, my code works. Start by exactly copying my code (change the component name), both markup and JavaScript, and then work from there. You have other typos that may be affecting your logic, `lightning-Card` should be `lightning-card`, for example. JavaScript and the markup are case-sensitive, so you need to be very observant in the code you write.

Comment: ok. thank you for your support